# Does pry cache local files for each terminal tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, pry, pry-rails

I'm working with a local library (gem), let's call it `B`, inside my rails application `A` (Rails version 6.0.2.2)

In `A`'s Gemfile, I require `B` via:

```
gem 'B', path: '../B'
```

When I do `rails c` with pry, I can access `B` and all its content correctly. However, when I make a local change to `B` and reopen `rails c`, the changes are not reflected.

If I quit the terminal (Mac OS) tab where I opened `rails c` and open another tab, suddenly all the changes that I made to `B` are reflected.

Does pry cache anything behind the scenes that's causing this flakiness?

Comment: You should check [how rails does class reloading and autoloading] (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html). You can probably try `reload!` in pry to reload the environment which reloads environment. It is as good as exit console and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your console is not reloaded automatically by Rails when you make changes.

This is to prevent triggering unexpected behavior in your console if you mix new objects with stale objects. However, you can reload your console manually by calling [`reload!`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html#constant-reloading).

Note, however, that all references to previous objects may be stale. E.g.:

```rb
User.object_id # => 70331650131980
user = User.first
# update the code...
reload!
User.object_id # => 70331615972020
```

As you can see by the `object_id`, the class is not the same after a reload. Therefore the `user` instance will still point to the first version of your code, *before* reloading. Be sure to fetch a fresh user in that case.